# docker container ls shows no container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-stack

I am learning docker from [here](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/).
The "docker swarm init" command gives the following output:

> Swarm initialized: current node (oqo97zuwsetlmt9c89nmedqm0) is now a manager.
>
> To add a worker to this swarm, run the following command:
>
> docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-40tj00xamvizycpqt8o78w0c0nxck3ant78t3x70ztv6f1mth8-9la5fw5wx83sicsqeup8b41fi 192.168.65.3:2377
>
> To add a manager to this swarm, run 'docker swarm join-token manager' and follow the instructions.

The `docker service ps getstartedlab_web` shows me:

> Creating network getstartedlab_webnet
>
> Creating service getstartedlab_web

The "docker service ls" shows me:

[image: servicels]

The "docker service ps getstartedlab_web" outputs:

[image: image2]

However, `docker container ls` does not show any containers running.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. I found the issue. It was in the docker-compose.yml where I didn't give the correct "username" in the "username/repo:tag".